# Специфический кейс касательно fragment restoration

Tags: java, android, kotlin, android-fragment

Проблема в том, что после того, как я помещаю приложение в бекграунд, фрагменты уничтожаются, а затем, когда я возвращаю приложение на передний план, оно воссоздает старые фрагменты, и в соответствии с приложением логика создает дополнительное еще новые инстансы этих фрагментов.

Теперь детальнее, чтобы проверить поведение приложения в случае нехватки памяти, я включил в параметрах разработчика `Don't keep activity`, то есть это означает, что каждый раз, когда я помещаю приложение в бекграунд, все активити уничтожаются и когда я возвращаю приложение, UI будет ресториться.

Теперь об архитектуре приложения, во-первых, навигация реализована с помощью navigation component `NavHostFragment`, во-вторых, у него есть activity, которая включает в себя фрагмент, который имеет `tablayout` с `viewpager`. Tablayout имеет 2 таба, каждый из которых это тоже фрагмент. Итак, `Activity -> fragment -> tablayout -> 2 more fragments`.

По логам видно, что после создания UI у меня есть 2 PlanFragment, затем я ставлю приложение в фон, в результате эти фрагменты получают `onDestroy`, это нормально, но если я пробую вернуть приложение из бекграунда, оно воссоздает 2 PlanFragment (без вызова метода newInstance), а затем (согласно логике) вызывается метод newInstance и создается еще 2 PlanFragment, в результате у меня есть 4 фрагмента PlanFragment.

```
=== start create UI ===
43.583  E  AuthActivity onCreate: 186118056
43.630  E  AuthPackageSelectionFragment onCreate: 197020657, parent: NavHostFragment{88ff3d6} (77945dff-a9c2-4f9f-8e11-8218dbd604bf id=0x7f0a050d)
43.798  E  create tablyout fragments AuthPackageSelectionFragment onCreate: 197020657
43.799  E  newInstance PlanFragment 
43.799  E  newInstance PlanFragment 
43.825  E  PlanFragment onCreate: 95398784
43.990  E  PlanFragment onCreate: 205178621
=== UI created ===
=== put app in the background ===
08.787  E  AuthActivity onDestroy: 186118056
08.789  E  PlanFragment onDestroy: 95398784
08.790  E  PlanFragment onDestroy: 205178621
08.801  E  AuthPackageSelectionFragment onDestroy: 197020657, parent: NavHostFragment{88ff3d6} (77945dff-a9c2-4f9f-8e11-8218dbd604bf id=0x7f0a050d)
=== app in the background ===
=== bring app back to foregraund ===
19.757  E  AuthPackageSelectionFragment onCreate: 141365020, parent: NavHostFragment{cb22725} (77945dff-a9c2-4f9f-8e11-8218dbd604bf id=0x7f0a050d)
19.758  E  PlanFragment onCreate: 42083764
19.760  E  PlanFragment onCreate: 129334143
19.761  E  AuthActivity onCreate: 24560031
19.848  E  AuthPackageSelectionFragment onDestroy: 141365020, parent: NavHostFragment{cb22725} (77945dff-a9c2-4f9f-8e11-8218dbd604bf id=0x7f0a050d)
19.850  E  AuthPackageSelectionFragment onCreate: 175242279, parent: NavHostFragment{cb22725} (77945dff-a9c2-4f9f-8e11-8218dbd604bf id=0x7f0a050d)
20.213  E  create tablyout fragments AuthPackageSelectionFragment onCreate: 175242279
20.213  E  newInstance PlanFragment 
20.213  E  newInstance PlanFragment 
20.256  E  PlanFragment onCreate: 96753467
20.380  E  PlanFragment onCreate: 218872921
=== state restored ===
```

Насколько я понимаю, одним из возможных решений здесь может быть если как то сделать, чтоб апп не сохраняло фрагменты для рестора так как эти фрагменты будут созданы в соответствии с флоу который создаст их как только parent фрагмент будет создан.

Что не так?

P.S. Если `Don't keep activity` выключено то приложение работает так как ожидается

Comment: "а затем (согласно логике) вызывается метод newInstance" - можно подробнее что эта за логика и откуда она взялась?

Comment: @Wlad ну табы создаются динамически, то есть когда апп поднимается делается запрос и на основе этого запроса создаются табы (фрагменты) и устанавливаются во вьюпейджер

Comment: Возможно, для вас будет актуально одно из решений из этого [вопроса](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15519214/prevent-fragment-recovery-in-android).